# Is it possible to configure voila to shutdown when the tab is closed?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython, voila

### Context

I try to execute voila dashboards in a `nox` isolated environment to facilitate development iterations and sharing. the problem is once the `nox` session is launching voila, it never finishes as voila is not closing itself when I close the tab.

## Question

**How to make the voila command close when the browser tab is closed?**
or (as its equivalent)
**How to make the voila command close when the kernel is shut down**

## How to reproduce

1. create a test.ipynb file with a simple `print("hello world")` cell
2. start voila by running `voila test.ipynb`
3. close the tab
4. The terminal will catch the "[Voila] Kernel shutdown: xxxxx" by remain active
5. only way to stop it is to run `ctrl+c`

Comment: Did you check out [this reply to 'How to programmatically quit Voilà?' from this point](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/864#issuecomment-811925569) and onward? There's a few approaches there. [enricogandini's comments](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/864#issuecomment-812399291) and [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/864#issuecomment-812400281) look particularly helpful.

Comment: I did but this thread is about closing it from the notebook itself right ? here I would like to kill the process on browser tab close (i.e. kernel is already dead)

Comment: I think closing from the notebook itself is in there, too maybe, but the approaches are related. My understanding was certain approaches were combining things at startup so that when the window exits, it all is shut down. Or that you can run commands in the terminal on the machine running it to shut it down.